# Terraform AWS Provider V2?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Could someone please clear up my confusion?

I see that there is a version 2 of the Terraform AWS provider.  The documentation states:

```
NOTE: This upgrade guide is a work in progress and will not be completed until the
 release of version 2.0.0 of the provider later this year.
```

The web page doesn't contain a date, so I'm unclear when "later this year" is.  2018 or 2019?

Given that this is a Hashicorp developed provider, I should be able to have the plugin automatically installed using the

```
terraform init
```

command, correct?  If so, doing this resulted in the error:

```
No provider "aws" plugins meet the constraint "~> 2.0".
```

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been released yet. You're looking at the [upgrade guide](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/guides/version-2-upgrade.html) which is being maintained with ongoing deprecations until it's released.

The V2 version will almost certainly land when Terraform core 0.12 does as this includes some breaking changes with how providers work.

When the V2 version of the AWS provider is released the linked documentation should make it easier for people to upgrade and handle anything that was deprecated in V1.